# RIA Services / Silverlight - Is there a test tool? Autoload fails

Tags: silverlight, ria

My problem (and solution?) is simple - I hope :)

I have a RIA Domain service built and a SL3 client. All this stuff compiles clean, and the authentication stuff works (login, log out, register). However, I cannot load data into a grid.

```
           <riaControls:DomainDataSource x:Name="dds" 
                    AutoLoad="True"
                    QueryName="GetCmsPageSetQuery"
                    LoadSize="20">
                <riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
                    <App:CoreDataDomainContext/>
                </riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
            </riaControls:DomainDataSource>

            <data:DataGrid
                Height="500"
                x:Name="dataGrid1"
                AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Data, ElementName=dds}"
            >
            </data:DataGrid>
```

I have checked that "GetCmsPageSetQuery" is valid, but I have no good way of verifyign that it is actually returning data (I will proba later with fiddler) and I wonder if there si a better way to test the domain service? Liek an interactive linqpad style tool?

I can only assume the query is failing to return data, because the grid stays empty (not even column headers).

Ken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XAML seems okay.  You can subscribe to the DomainDataSource.LoadedData event, as well as the DomainDataSource.LoadError event to see what's going on.  LoadError events will be raised if something happened that prevented it from calling the load from the server.  LoadedData will be raised if it hits the server, and you can see error information from the event's args.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - subscribing to those events led me to the exception ( a connection string error ).

To bab there isnt a test harness though :)